# Does California SB611 require Hollywood to hire more diverse talent?

Tags: california, discrimination

I was reading a news article in which it was mentioned that there is a new bill (SB-611) proposing which will encourage racial and LGBTQ diversity and inclusion in movies.

I have read the summary of the [bill](https://fastdemocracy.com/bill-search/ca/20212022/bills/CAB00022581/) but it was more related to taxation.

I have two questions:

1. Is this bill really forced Hollywood industries to hire more diverse talent (actors/actress) such as minority or LGBTQ communities.
2. Is this bill have been passed as a Law ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of background: In California, [current law](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/revenue-and-taxation-code/rtc-sect-17053-98.html) already provides tax incentives to producers who agree to shoot their films in California, under certain conditions. One of those conditions is that their application describe any programs they have voluntarily adopted to increase the number of "women and minorities" in specific job classifications.

SB 611 would broaden that requirement, requiring producers to describe any programs they have voluntarily adopted to increase the number of "individuals from underserved communities" in any job.

1. No, the bill would not require anyone to hire diverse talent. It would only require producers who want to avoid paying taxes to describe how they try to increase hiring of people from underserved communities. If that plan is "do nothing," the producer can say so and remain eligible for the credit.
2. SB 611 is not law. It was passed by the Senate, but it needs to return to the Assembly and then be sent to the governor for a signature. It has been nearly a month since there has been any major movement on it, so it seems unlikely that the bill will become law this session.